# How can I delete a subArray, if search values matches?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to working with arrays and I am stuck on being able to delete an entry.

If I have:

```
$del_itemid = 58;
$del_modiifier = 1;
```

How do I search through my array `$orders` and unset the array containing these variables ?

```
$orders =  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 67
            [modifier] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [unit_price] => 17.00
            [categoryid] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 58
            [modifier] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [unit_price] => 18.00
            [categoryid] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [itemid] => 72
            [modifier] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            [unit_price] => 10.00
            [categoryid] => 3
        )

)
```

**EDIT:**

This is what I have been trying:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($orders as $key => $value) {

    $itemid = $value['itemid'];
    $modifier = $value['modifier'];

    if ($itemid == $del_itemid && $modifier == $del_modifier)  {
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$i]);
        break;                  
    }

    $i++;

}
```

Comment: I did originally try a for each loop with a counter to get the index first but this did not work after a few items had been deleted and the index was no longer in order.

Comment: ^^ Add this attempt to your question and show some effort.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to check 2 values, I would use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to loop through the array and filter all subArrays out, where both values are equal to your search values, e.g.

```
$newArray = array_filter($orders, function($v)use($del_itemid, $del_modiifier){
    if($v["itemid"] == $del_itemid && $v["modifier"] == $del_modiifier)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
});
```

Comment: Tighter: `return $v["itemid"] != $del_itemid && $v["modifier"] != $del_modiifier;`

Comment: The disadvantage of `array_filter()` is that it cannot be halted by a `break` after the match is found.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on what I was originally trying to achieve with the loop. If I use `array_splice()` instead of `unset()` it will reset the index so that it remains possible to loop through the array without there being holes in the index:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($orders as $key => $value) {

    $itemid = $value['itemid'];
    $modifier = $value['modifier'];

    if ($itemid == $del_itemid && $modifier == $del_modifier)   {
        array_splice($orders, $i,1);       
    }    

    $i++;  

}
```

Comment: `$key` is the index (which, because you are re-indexing on every mutation, is reliably also the position that `array_splice()` wants) so you should use this instead of `$i`. Where did your `break` go? it is best practice when you expect to only find one match.  https://3v4l.org/rJa6a